# Android resource linking failed (AAPT: error) when importing a library as source code into project

Tags: android

All the while, I'm importing library using the following way

```
implementation 'com.github.yccheok:CalendarView:1.13'
```

https://github.com/yccheok/CalendarView

However, I need to perform debugging on the library itself. So, it will be way easier for me to import the library as source code.

I believe I'm doing it correctly. I go to File/ Project structure

[image]

After "Import Gradle Project", I getting the following

[image]

---

However, when I compile, previously, some XML layouts which previously workable are broken. For instance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...

    <com.haibin.calendarview.CalendarLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/calendarBackgroundColor"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:calendar_show_mode="both_month_week_view" <-- ERROR HERE
        app:default_status="expand"
        app:calendar_content_view_id="@+id/recycler_view">
```

I'm getting **Android resource linking failed** with detailed message

```
AAPT: error: attribute calendar_content_view_id (aka com.yocto.wenote:calendar_content_view_id) not found.
```

Does anyone have idea why such error occur, and how we can resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: check `app:select_mode=` property instead of  `app:calendar_show_mode` . I am not sure.

Comment: https://github.com/huanghaibin-dev/CalendarView/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_custom.xml